# Fibonacci basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, fibonacci-numbers

Exercise 2.1. The set Fib, consisting of all the Fibonacci-type sequences, is a subspace of$ \ V$ with dimension 2.

Show that the sequences $ s$ and $t$ form a basis of Fib, where $s_0 = 1, s_1 = 0, t_0 = 0$ and $t_1 = 1.$

[This is where I found the question](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/REU11/lin2.pdf)

What is the linear transformation of $vector{0
1} and matrix{1 0}$?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that the Fibonacci-type sequence given by $f_0 = a$ and $f_1 = b$ can be written as $f = a s + b t$

Comment: This only gives me the first two terms, how can I extend this equation to get the whole sequence?

Comment: @Sarah.B by paying close attention to what a "Fibonacci-type sequence" is.

Comment: @Sarah.B what does the sequence $(a,b,\dots)$ look like? We want to show that we can write it as $$
a (1,0,1,1,2,\dots) + b(0,1,1,2,3,\dots)
$$.

Comment: $(a,b,a+b,a+2b,2a+3b, 3a+5b,....)$

Comment: @Sarah.B now, can you show what I'm telling you to show?

Comment: yes but I can't work out the $n^{th}$ term, what would the last term be?

Comment: You know what it should be in terms of the $n$th terms of $s$ and $t$. Use induction to prove that the formula actually works

Comment: I don't think I know.

Comment: @Sarah.B well I think you should try.  And if you're still stuck once you have, ask a new question in which you explain, to some small extent, what you have tried so far.